# How to perform Click action on Button or Text field by pywinauto

Tags: pywinauto

I'm using pywinauto to automation Click on some button on DiffDaff software.

My intention are:

- Step 1: Open DiffDaff software
- Step 2: Click 'About' button

  ```
  from pywinauto.application import Application

  app = Application.start("C:\Program Files\DiffDaff\DiffDaff.exe")

  app.About.Click()
  ```

But, I'm on stuck at step 2, and the console show error:

```
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\pywinauto\application.py", line 238, in __getattr__
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\pywinauto\application.py", line 788, in _resolve_control
pywinauto.findbestmatch.MatchError: Could not find 'About' in '['', u'DiffDaff - Compare Files, Folders And Web Pages', u'Internet Explorer_Hidden', u'DiffDaff - Compare Files, Folders And Web PagesDialog', 'Dialog']'
```

Where, '', u'DiffDaff - Compare Files, Folders And Web Pages', u'Internet Explorer_Hidden', u'DiffDaff - Compare Files, Folders And Web PagesDialog', 'Dialog' is the title of sotfware

Also, using the command `'app.dialogs.print_control_identifiers()'` to know what exact position of 'About' button, there is the output:

```
Button - '&About'   (L750, T388, R834, B411)
    '&About' '&AboutButton' 'Button3'
```

But it's so difficult to understand the parameter as above (what/where is L750, T388,...) - Would you like to explain all the mean of parameters as above ?

And the way to perform 'Click' button ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`pywinauto` requires 2-level hierarchy from Application object to control method. The structure of any call is

```
app.<DialogName>.<ControlName>.<method>(<params>)
```

In your case it should look like

```
app.Dialog.About.click()
```

If you need more realistic click, please use `click_input()` which moves cursor and clicks the control as user. `click()` only sends `WM_CLICK` and it's less reliable also.

`print_control_identifiers()` method prints the following information:

```
<ControlType> - '<Name a la WindowText>' (<rectangle>)
                possible names which are most likely useful for object attribute access
```

Mentioned code is equivalent to the following:

```
app.window(best_match='Dialog', top_level_only=True).child_window(best_match='About').click()
```

`pywinauto` simplifies such constructions by overriding `__getattribute__` method.

Comment: Thanks, it works! I'd like to know "(L750, T388, R834, B411)" will create (-|-) - is that right. and what the meaning of " '&About' '&AboutButton' 'Button3'"

Comment: '&About' is a real WindowText() of the button. 'Button' is FriendlyClassName(). All possible names for `__getattr__` method have 3 variants: '<Text>', '<Text><ClassName>' and '<ClassName>i' where _i_ is an index of control of such type. For example, you can identify first button by 'Button0' or 'Button1', second button name can be 'Button2', and so on. This is useful for cases when you don't have texts or they are the same.

Comment: "(L750, T388, R834, B411)" is an absolute screen rectangle of the control. L means "left", R - "right", etc.

Comment: What is this "Dialog".?does it refer to the title of the window,How do i find this.?